# Java Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, package

I have download spring framework - spring-framework-3.1.0.M2-with-docs.zip.
In manifest file:

```
Import-Package: commonj.timers;version="[1.1.0, 2.0.0)";resolution:="o ptional",
commonj.work;version="[1.1.0, 2.0.0)";resolution:="optional" ,
freemarker.cache;version="[2.3.14, 3.0.0)";resolution:="optional",
..................................
```

Exists some tool with which I can download this enormous quantity of packages may be from Maven repository?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven the dependencies will be downloaded automatically => I'd suggest using maven

Answer (score 1):

The Import-Package header is an OSGi header. If you're using OSGi, you might need some additional configuration in your project. Otherwise, take Bozho's advice and just use Maven.